# How to Display values(Integers) in an array in a series of Text-boxes in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, windows-forms-designer

Before I start let me state that I am a complete nub when it comes to programming and if this question has been asked somewhere else please direct me to it(although I did a thorough search but wasn't able to find a proper concise answer.

I created a Windows form application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010  in which I gather values from 6 textboxes and store them in an array.. at the click of a button.

Now I want to display those taken values in another series of 6 textboxes. How do I do that.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[] sortingarray = new int [6];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void bubble_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
        {
            sortingarray[a] = int.Parse(value1.Text);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: you have the `sortingarray` now you just assign the values of the `sortingarray` to the TextBox.Text property of course using the proper casting and or conversion.. you do not need a for loop just do this for all the textboxes 
`sortingarray[0] = int.Parse(value1.Text); sortingarray[1] = int.Parse(value2.Text);....etc`  assuming the name of your textboxes are called value use proper naming convention when naming controls such as textboxes like `txtSomeName` `value` is a reserved word

Comment: if you need the for loop please keep in mind that all the texboxes will have the same value. but even after the for loop you should still be able to assign the values to those textboxes .Text ... show the name of the 6 textboxes please as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above will take the text from ONE textbox (value1) and add it six times to an array. You might name your textboxes txtBox1 - txtBox6 and change your line of code to:

```
TextBox t = Controls.Find("txtBox"+a.ToString(),true)[0] as TextBox;
sortingarray[a] = int.Parse(t.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to display in 6 different textboxes, I would suggest to create a list of textbox and assign value using Linq.

```
List<TextBox> lst = new List<TextBox>();
lst.Add(textBox1);
lst.Add(textBox2);
lst.Add(textBox2); //likewise, add all six in the list box
textBox.Text = "5"; // for example
lst.ForEach(j => j.Text = textBox.Text);
```